# Swing toggled buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have a basic question about Toggled button: the following code does generate a desired result, however, it seems the boolean value should be opposite. Is the code programmatically correct?

```
public class ToggleButton extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ToggleButton() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        one = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        all = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        one.setText("one channel");
        one.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                oneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        all.setText("all channel");
        all.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                allActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(all)
                    .addComponent(one))
                .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(one)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(all)
                .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void allActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
         if("all".equals(evt.getActionCommand())){
                all.setSelected(false);
                one.setSelected(true);
            }else {
                one.setSelected(false);
                all.setSelected(true);
            }              
    }                                   

    private void oneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    

         if("one".equals(evt.getActionCommand())){
                one.setSelected(false);
                all.setSelected(true); 
            }else{
             all.setSelected(false);
             one.setSelected(true);
         }
    }                                   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ToggleButton.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ToggleButton.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ToggleButton.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ToggleButton.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ToggleButton().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton all;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton one;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: Has to be correct if you are using a GUI builder.

Comment: Most of the code was generated by IDE, what confusing is the  allActionPerformed and oneActionPerformed event handler, if one channel is clicked, shouldn't one.setSelected under oneActionPerformed be true, vice versa?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve.What you want output?Which should be false?For better help sooner, post an SSCCE

Answer (score 3):

Your tests `if("all".equals(evt.getActionCommand()))` and `if("one".equals(evt.getActionCommand()))` are always `false` since you never set any `actionCommand` on your `JRadioBuitton`'s. Now, I really don't get why you are trying to set the value of the radio button while the UI has already done so. You should not have to remodify the state of the button.

What you may lack is a [`ButtonGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) (and add both `JRadioButton`'s to that group) so that when one JRadioButton is selected the other gets automatically deselected.

Comment: +1 I din't noticed that those buttons belong to same group or not.Thats why they both can be selected.